# Accidentally caulked wrong areas on window install?

Tags: windows, caulking, caulk

I'm installing an exterior window for the first time and think I made a dumb rookie move with the exterior caulk. I've caulked between the window trim and the siding, including underneath the sill. My house has cedar shake shingles, if that matters.

Areas caulked that I think I maybe shouldn't have...:

- Between siding (cedar shake) and the new wooden exterior window trim
- Underneath the sill

Should these areas have caulk or no caulk?

If no caulk, any recommendations on how to remove the caulk? I used DAP230.

[image]
[image]

Comment: All of this is less important than what you did with the flashing. What does your flashing look like and what pattern did you follow there?

Comment: Also, if the window frame has drain (weep) holes on bottom, are they blocked?